# Simple web server hangs when receiving http request

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm writing a simple web server,code snippet:

```
 ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);  
  Socket client=server.accept();  
  InputStream in=client.getInputStream();  
  OutputStream out=client.getOutputStream();  
  int val = -1;  
  while ((val = in.read()) != -1) {  
    System.out.print((char) val);  
  }   
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( out));  
  writer.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\nhello world!");  
  writer.close();  
  out.close();  
  in.close();
```

I run it on my computer,then visit http://127.0.0.1 in Firefox.  The page hangs and could'nt show "hello world".I think the problem occurs in `while ((val = in.read()) != -1)`,how to solve it?

Comment: You have to follow the HTTP protocol (which is much more complicated than it appears at first sight). You'll have to read one request(the HTTP spec will tell you the rules), and then send the response, not loop until the end of the stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP (at least the 1.1 version) allows letting the connection open. The request is then ended by an empty line (i.e. `"\r\n\r\n"`), if it is not a POST or PUT request with contents. After this, the client can send the next request on the same connection.

So you have to read the input at least for scanning for your empty line.

---

Edit: To clarify this a bit, some quotes from [RFC 2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (which defines HTTP 1.1).

Section **4.1, Message Types**:

> Request (section 5) and Response (section 6) messages use the generic
>     message format of RFC 822 [9] for transferring entities (the payload
>     of the message). Both types of message consist of a start-line, zero
>     or more header fields (also known as "headers"), an empty line (i.e.,
>     a line with nothing preceding the CRLF) indicating the end of the
>     header fields, and possibly a message-body.
>
> ```
>    generic-message = start-line
>                      *(message-header CRLF)
>                      CRLF
>                      [ message-body ]
>    start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line
> ```

So, message header and message body are delimited by an empty line (the first one after the start line).

Section **4.3 Message Body**:

> The message-body (if any) of an HTTP message is used to carry the
>     entity-body associated with the request or response. [...]
>
> The rules for when a message-body is allowed in a message differ for
>     requests and responses.
>
> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
>     inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in
>     the request's message-headers. A message-body MUST NOT be included in
>     a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1)
>     does not allow sending an entity-body in requests. A server SHOULD
>     read and forward a message-body on any request; if the request method
>     does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the
>     message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request.

So in principle, clients must only send a body when the method allows it, but servers should ignore superfluous message bodies, if they are sent on a method that does not support it. And the presence of a body is indicated by the `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding` header fields.

The subsections of section 9 define the individual methods.

- 9.2 OPTIONS

  - can contain a body, but meaning is not defined
- 9.3 GET

  - can contain no body
- 9.4 HEAD

  - can contain no body
- 9.5 POST

  - should (or must?) contain a body
- 9.6 PUT

  - should (or must?) contain a body
- 9.7 DELETE

  - can contain no body
- 9.8 TRACE

  - can contain no body
- 9.9 CONNECT

  - (this method is reserved)

Anyway, independently of whether the client sends a body or not, and whether it reuses the connection for the next request or not, it will normally not close the connection before the response is read, since otherwise your server could not resend the response at all. So you simply can't wait on a close when reading the request, but have to somehow know when it ended to send your response.

For your simple hello world server which only handles get requests you can simply say "read until the first empty line".

For a real server (i.e. one that is visible to the outside world), you should at least parse the request, ignore any body, and handle HEAD differently than GET (that is, not sending any body back), and send error responses for unsupported methods.

Comment: \r\n\r\n terminates the headers, not the request. The content must have a defined length, either via the Content-Length header or the sum of the lengths of the multiparts.

Comment: @EJP: If we have a GET-request, it does only consist of the header, or do I err here?

Comment: Correct, a GET request has no body.

Comment: I've added the proper HTTP header as well as the "\r\n\r\n" at the end, but the page socket connection still never closes after the page load. In my case, since the content returned is dynamic, I can't really set content length first thing when a connection is made...